# Android SQLite UPDATE with parametrized WHERE does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

This query fails to update (updated is 0):

```
int updated = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values,
   COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID + "= ? AND " + COLUMN_NAME_TOPIC + "= ?",
   new String[] { String.valueOf(id), name });
```

But this works just fine, updated = 1:

```
int updated = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values,
   COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID + "=" + id + 
       " AND " + COLUMN_NAME_TOPIC + "='" + name + "'",
   null);
```

The only difference is how WHERE is constructed - explicitly or through parameters. What's going on?

SQLite 3.8.10.2 in stock Android emulator.

Comment: In the second example, you quoted the `name` value

Comment: Yes, the 'name' is a string, so I quoted it. In the first example SQLite is supposed to quote it automatically, is it not?.

Comment: I tried this: 
      COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID + "= ? AND " + COLUMN_NAME_TOPIC + "= '?'",

Comment: and it failed in a different way: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  10 arguments were provided but the statement needs 9 arguments.

Comment: 10 arguments were provided? You only have two question marks and two arguments... Are you sure the error was on that same line?

Comment: ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Comment: The 'values' contains the first 8 arguments.

Comment: Here is what the query looks like when it's expanded: 

      UPDATE topics SET priv=?,seq=?,recv=?,mode=?,read=?,updated=?,last_used=?,pub=? WHERE account_id= ? AND name= ?

Comment: Okay, and this is why we ask you create a [mcve]. Your code is minimal, but far from complete

Comment: @cricket_007 what would you say is missing to qualify as complete?

Answer (score 0):

The `account_id` column contains numbers. A comparison against a string (`String.valueOf(id)`) will never succeed.

The Android database API supports only string parameters here, so you must insert the ID directly into the string:

```java
int updated = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values,
      COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID + "=" + id + " AND " + COLUMN_NAME_TOPIC + "= ?",
      new String[] { name });
```

Comment: sqlite does not care that much about types

Comment: It's not exactly apples to apples, but here is an code sample from Google where it uses parametrized query comparing numeric field to a string: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java#L194

Comment: That works only if the column has correct [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity); yours hasn't.

Comment: @CL: I'm not sure why you think it's wrong affinity. Here are the relevant definitions: `CREATE TABLE accounts (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,...);
CREATE TABLE topics (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,account_id REFERENCES accounts(_id),name TEXT,...);`
The COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID is `account_id` is a reference type which should be the same as the `_id`, i.e. `INTEGER`.

Comment: To clarify, in google's sample I referenced above, the string id is bound to an integer column. See line [194](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java#L194) and [225](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java#L225)

Comment: In general I'm not looking for a workaround. I already have one. I want to understand why it does not work.